# Python - Shapely to convert 2 columns to WKB

Tags: python, shapely, well-known-binary

I have 2 columns in a CSV called Longitude and Latitude which are being parsed using my Python AWS Lambda Code.

I am using the shapely module with the following code to convert the long/lats into geometry format

```
g = wkt.loads('POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)')
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print (new)
```

Is there a way to call the two columns so that each entry is given their wkb, rather than put each point in individually?

e.g.

```
g = wkt.loads('POINT('longitude' 'latitude')')
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print (new)
```

Comment: Work directly with shapely Point(-longitude, latitude)  instead of WKT

Comment: @gene oh thank you! I then get the error ```'str' object has no attribute '_geom'``` Am I to do some conversion before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables (or a list of longitudes/latitudes)

```
longitude = -2.5378432182396935
latitude = 55.20394960316738
```

With the original shapely [Point](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#points) geometry:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
g = Point(longitude,latitude)
from shapely import wkb
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print(new)
0101000020E610000010B8C5BE804D04C06BD145051B9A4B40
```

But as it is also a pure Python problem you can use the standard solutions  ([Inserting values into strings](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html)):

With the string format method

```
wkt = "Point({} {})".format(longitude,latitude)
print(wkt)
POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)
```

With f-strings in Python >= 3.6:

```
wkt =  f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})'
print(wkt)
POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)
```

With old school % formatting

```
wkt = "POINT(%s %s)" % (longitude,latitude)
print(wkt)
POINT(-2.5378432182396935 55.20394960316738)
```

After

```
g = wkt.loads( wkt)
new = wkb.dumps(g, hex=True, srid=4326)
print(new)
0101000020E610000010B8C5BE804D04C06BD145051B9A4B40
```